# Hibernate, dar formato a campo numerico

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Como puedo indicar con JPA que un campo que es entero tenga este formato "00001". O sea, 5 dígitos que se completen con ceros por delante.

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres que se muestre? ¿Usando qué framework?

Comment: en la BD que se guarde así. Pero lo estoy generando todo con el Hibernate.

Comment: Tienes que tener tener en cuenta que 00001 si lo pasas a entero es 1. Para dejarlo con los 0 tendrías que cambiar el tipo a VARCHAR porque eso al final es una cadena de caracteres.